# Connection Reset in Java but Working with Postman

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, post, certificate

I am facing a problem with a Post Method with Java.
Here is my code

```
final HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(formrequest.length()));
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.connect();

        try (DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.writeBytes(formrequest);
        }
        is = conn.getInputStream();
        final BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
        final String jsonText = readAll(rd);

        final JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
        return json;
```

The exception that I get when I try to connect is

```
21:14:51.661 [main] ERROR it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.TokenGetter - Unable to get Token for DDS Service
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.
                                 connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.TokenGetter.getDdsToken(TokenGetter.java:166)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.TokenGetter.refresh(TokenGetter.java:116)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.TokenGetter.getValidToken(TokenGetter.java:98)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.AbstractDdsDaoImpl.getValidToken(AbstractDdsDaoImpl.java:30)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.AbstractDdsDaoImpl.sendPostRequest(AbstractDdsDaoImpl.java:48)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.DdsFolderDaoImpl.find(DdsFolderDaoImpl.java:68)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
Exception in thread "main" it.snam.ned.libs.dds.errors.DdsException: java.net.SocketException:   Connection reset
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.TokenGetter.getDdsToken(TokenGetter.java:183)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.TokenGetter.refresh(TokenGetter.java:116)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.TokenGetter.getValidToken(TokenGetter.java:98)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.AbstractDdsDaoImpl.getValidToken(AbstractDdsDaoImpl.java:30)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.AbstractDdsDaoImpl.sendPostRequest(AbstractDdsDaoImpl.java:48)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.DdsFolderDaoImpl.find(DdsFolderDaoImpl.java:68)
at Main.main(Main.java:17)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:209)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readV3Record(InputRecord.java:593)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:532)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:559)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
at it.snam.ned.libs.dds.v2.TokenGetter.getDdsToken(TokenGetter.java:166)
... 6 more
```

But If I try to connect with Postman everything is fine. This is the request from Postman

[Postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhqAp.png)

This is the Certificate of the Server I am trying to reach

[SSL Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mNUBs.png)

This is what I tried and did not work.

1. Download the JCE Policy 8 and put in the security path of JRE
2. Use the `RestTemplate` but got the same error

More info:
I used both JDK 1.8.0_111 and JDK 1.8.0_221